# how do i verify an email from the database?

Tags: php, mysql

i tried verifying and email from my database, but it won't check if it exist or not, please how do it fix it?
here i what i've tried out;

```
<?php
function SignIn()
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password007", "voting");

    $email = $_POST['email'];

if(!empty($email))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, 
is it empty or have some text
{
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Email, VotersID FROM voters where Email = '$email' ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if(!empty($row['Email']))
    {

        $_SESSION['Email'] = $row['Email'];
        $votersID = $row['VotersID'];

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){alert("Message have been sent to your email.");}</script>';


    }
    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){alert("Email not found! Please try again.");}</script>';
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
    SignIn();
}
          ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. DO NOT use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, as it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You need to better debug your problem.  Add breakpoints, add mysqli error handling, etc.

Comment: there's no jquery here (I removed the tag and added the mysql tag in an edit) and you have a variable scope issue. Error reporting would have told you about an undefined variable notic.